# Clone private git repo to remote host using sudo

Tags: linux, git, ssh, sudo

I would like to run the following command:

```
ssh -A josh@remote_ip sudo git clone git@github.com:private/private-repo.git /home/ec2-user/private-repo
```

but I get an error:

```
Cloning into '/home/ec2-user/private-repo'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The command works when I want to clone into a directory I own (`~/private-repo`) without `sudo`. The command doesn't work if I include `sudo` into a directory I already own.

Since I need to use `sudo` to write into the other user's directory, how can I get this command to work? Logging in as `ec2-user` is not a possible solution.

Comment: When you run `git` with `sudo`, `ssh` is not looking in `~josh/.ssh` for the key any more; it's looking in `~root/.ssh`.

Comment: The simplest solution will be to clone to a directory you have access to, then use `sudo` to move it to the correct location.

Comment: Can you use `sudo` to run as `ec2-user` instead? You can create a dedicated key for that user and allow it to access the private repository using that key.

Comment: @chepner the end goal is to run this command using Ansible, where I already tried running it as `ec2-user` there with no luck. Your initial comment about ssh looking in `~root/.ssh` was very helpful and allowed me to find what I think is the best solution for my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @chepner for pointing me in the direction of the issue: my ssh key does not get passed to `~root/.ssh` when I use sudo.

To fix this, I used `visudo` to add this line to my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
Defaults    env_keep += "SSH_AUTH_SOCK"
```

[Source](https://serverfault.com/a/118932)