Github: Can't clone with ssh
I am trying to clone a private repository in a vps (or droplet) with linux, I followed all the steps in the official docs and when I run the command ssh -T git@github.com I get the successful message: Hi username You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access..
I also added the key to the agent with the command eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" and then ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
But I still can't clone my private repository, when I try to run this command sudo git clone git@github.com:username/repository.git I get the following error:
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Of course I replaced username and repository with my username and repository name
I don't really understand what happens, I don't know why I get a permissions denied if I get a successful connection through ssh.

Why are you using sudo?

Don't use sudo for git clone (or any git operations). Your ssh key isn't available when using sudo. If you really need to for some reason, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73709555/5774952

Hi, thanks for asking. If i don't use sudo i get this error: fatal: could not create work tree dir 'repository': Permission denied

Then change to a directory where your logged in user has write-access ... or, if you had previously run the same command w/ sudo in a directory where you do have write access: sudo chown -R youruser repository ...

sudo is going to use root's keys by default. If root doesn't have keys, or if root's keys aren't associated with your GitHub profile, then you'll get this. That's one reason why people are telling you not to use sudo.

Thanks for your responses, i am a kind of new using Linux and I wanted to clone my repository in the 'srv' folder and it seems that I had to modify permissions temporarily with chmod. i used sudo chmod 777 srv. Thanks for your responses

@DanielValencia - as long as there's nothing else under /srv the 777 should be fine; generally speaking it's a bad idea, the only place in the file system with those permissions should be /tmp which also has the sticky bit set ... please update your question with the output of ls -l / and ls -l /srv P.S.: if you mention people w/ an @tink, for instance, in comments they'll get a notification - that can reduce turn-around times.

Meta: Please summarize the comments into an answer.

@bbaassssiiee - how? We don't know the outcomes (can't say whether any of this actually provided a solution - at this stage it's all guessing and trouble-shooting advice).
